# Inserting from one Mysql database to Another

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to transfer data from one mysql db to another .For one i have the connection url as the db name ,username and pwd (As this has to be present on the remote location).And for another I am using a data source .

```
public class errorlog {
     public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try {
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded mysql1server");
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded mysql");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("not loaded");
            }
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/db1" ;

              String connectionUrl2="jdbc:odbc:test";
                Connection con=null;
                Connection con2=null;
                Statement stmt = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = null;


                try {
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,"root","root");
                    System.out.println("CONNECTED1 mysql1");
                 con2 = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl2);
              System.out.println("CONNECTED2 mysql");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                try {
                 stmt = con.createStatement();
                 rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * FROM db1.db1_table");
                  System.out.print("Select executed");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


               try {
                    while (rs.next()) {

                        int col1 = rs.getInt("col1");
                        String col2=rs.getString("col2");


Date TimeStamp = rs.getDate("Time Stamp");



                    String insertSql ="Insert into db2.db2_table (`col1`,`col2`) values(?,?)";
                            pstmt = con2.prepareStatement(insertSql);

                             pstmt.setInt(1,col1);
                            pstmt.setString(2,col2);


pstmt.setDate(3,(java.sql.Date) TimeStamp);

                            pstmt.executeUpdate();




                       pstmt.close();
                       System.out.println("insert done");
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("out insert done");


    }
    }
```

I am getting an error as "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/databaseName=db1;user=root;password=root"

Please let me know where i am wrong.

Further requirement -

I want to use a configuration file which will hold a time value and will keep on updating as the data is fetched .Ex- file holds value 2014-03-18 12:00:00,the program will run in a periodic interval of 1 hour .I want to fetch data only after the file holding time .And once run the file should be updated .

Please let me know how can i do dat .

Answer (score 0):

You didnt load the MySQL driver. You got the ODBC driver with

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
```

but you'll need something for the mysql jdbc protocol, e.g.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

and will then need to reference / include the mysql connector jar in your project.

Comment: changed as per your suggestion and the jar is already added .Still the same error .Have edited the code above

Comment: I'm thinking it's frowning on the presence of your username and password in the connection URL. Try pulling those out and using DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root","root").

Comment: still the same error ..See the edited code pls..the 2 driver loaded statements are getting printed

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting an error as "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/databaseName=db1;user=root;password=root"

You need a colon after `mysql'

Comment: I used a colon .. now its sowing the error as "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application".

Comment: You try combining our answers?

Comment: that's a problem with your ODBC driver. you need to install the proper 32 or 64-bit driver to match your application

Comment: If both connections are to MySQL servers, you can use JDBC for both connections, no need for ODBC.....